# JAVA - How to combine two list?

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
public class Identifiers {
    public List<String> lowercase = Arrays.asList ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z");
    public List<String> uppercase = Arrays.asList ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"
                                        , "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V"
                                        , "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    public List<String> number = Arrays.asList("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");

}
public class ReservedSymbolsDelims {
    public List<String> delim_arithop = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", "(", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    public List<String> delim_5 = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", "(", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "\"");
    public List<String> delim_6 = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", "a", "b", "c" ,"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    public List<String> incop = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".", ",");
    public List<String> delim_7 = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z", "+", "-");
    public List<String> delim_8 = Arrays.asList (",", ".", "nl", "tab", " ", "!", "=", ")", ">", "<", "+", "-", "*", "/", "%");
    public List<String> delim_9 = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", ".", ",", ")", "!", "=", "+", "-", "*", "/", "%", ">", "<"
                                        , "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
                                        , "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                                        , "w", "x", "y", "z", "]");
    public List<String> delim_10 = Arrays.asList ("nl", "tab", " ", "/");
}
```

As you can see the list lowercase and number are also part of other numerous lists. I've tried using the .addAll(); but it didn't work.

Is there any other way I can add other list to another list? Thanks!

Comment: `addAll()` doesn't work on a list created by `Arrays.asList()`: it's a fixed-size list. You can certainly use `addAll` to add to an `ArrayList` (amongst many other types of list), though.

Comment: If you do not ever want duplicates, you may want to use Sets instead of Lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 then try the below code

```
List<String> mergelist = Stream.of(lowercase, number)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache library like that:

```
public List<String> alphabet = ListUtils.union(lowercase,uppercase);
```

More info: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html